# Blur box background in Nodejs canvas api

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, html5-canvas, node-canvas

I was searching for a way to blur behind a transparent box in `Nodejs` canvas `API`. Something like the apple glossy effect when opening a window etc. After researching I found an answer on StackOverflow that demonstrates how to achieve the effect. The code was working fine in the browser version of Canvas, but when I tried that code in Nodejs canvas API, it gave different results.

```js
var blurredRect = {
  x: 80,
  y: 80,
  height: 400,
  width: 400,
  spread: 10
};
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;
img.src = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?auto=format&fit=crop&q=80&w=2073&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D';

function draw() {
  canvas.width = img.width / 2;
  canvas.height = img.height / 2;
  // first pass draw everything
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
  // next drawings will be blurred
  ctx.filter = 'blur('+ blurredRect.spread +'px)';
  // draw the canvas over itself, cropping to our required rect
  ctx.drawImage(canvas,
    blurredRect.x, blurredRect.y, blurredRect.width, blurredRect.height,
    blurredRect.x, blurredRect.y, blurredRect.width, blurredRect.height
  );
  // draw the coloring (white-ish) layer, without blur
  ctx.filter = 'none'; // remove filter
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)';
  ctx.fillRect(blurredRect.x, blurredRect.y, blurredRect.width, blurredRect.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

When I tried the exact same code in Nodejs canvas api :-

```js
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
const fs = require('fs')

var blurredRect = {
    x: 80,
    y: 80,
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    spread: 10
  };

  const canvas = createCanvas(0, 0);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Load the background image
loadImage('path/to/newbrowser.png').then((background) => {

    canvas.width = background.width / 2;
    canvas.height = background.height / 2;
    // first pass draw everything
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
    // next drawings will be blurred
    ctx.filter = 'blur('+ blurredRect.spread +'px)';
    // draw the canvas over itself, cropping to our required rect
    ctx.drawImage(canvas,
      blurredRect.x, blurredRect.y, blurredRect.width, blurredRect.height,
      blurredRect.x, blurredRect.y, blurredRect.width, blurredRect.height
    );
    // draw the coloring (white-ish) layer, without blur
    ctx.filter = 'none'; // remove filter
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)';
    ctx.fillRect(blurredRect.x, blurredRect.y, blurredRect.width, blurredRect.height);

   const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream('path/to/blur.png');
    const stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
    stream.pipe(outputStream);
});
```

The above code gave this image as the result:-
[image: Nodejs output]